# Is "Am" instead of "I am" proper slang?

Tags: slang

I tried to coax google into finding results for "am not preceded by I", but failed.

Now my question is: Is saying "Am" instead of "I am" valid slang?

Examples:

- Am a God. Obey.
- Am driving. Can't talk now.
- Am a cat. Food plz.

By "grammatically correct slang", I mean if it's okay to use such sentences when talking, writing signs, registering domains, et al, when the intention is to not be serious, i.e. will native speakers understand?

Comment: It's conversational deletion. 'How slangy' it is is a matter of opinion. See John Lawler's answer, which concludes 'Let me reiterate that this phenomenon only occurs in speaking English, and in other informal communication systems like email and txting that work like speech. It is not good formal written style, except for reporting dialog in a story.'

Comment: All slang is grammatically correct. There is no ungrammatical slang. It does not exist. But that is actually beyond the point, because this is no slang in the first place.

Comment: Nice, thanks (and also thanks for duplicate-tion) )

Comment: There is no such thing as "proper" or "improper" slang.  Slang is purely a matter between the speaker and the person listening, and whether they are communicating satisfactorily.  It may employ expressions that are only meaningful to those two individuals.

Comment: So "Engrish", Baby-Language and Dog-Language are slangs, too? Unfortunately, that does not really fit my book's definition of slang.

Comment: You need to find a better book.

Comment: @HotLicks: My books were: https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aslang, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang, as well as hanging around some time in the internet. Nowhere is defined that slang is a matter of two persons only, but rather communities like the armed forces or the people of my hometown. Surely, the boundaries are very flexible. But I think nobody would agree that John and Jane's personal grunt-based hidden sexual dirty-talk that nobody understands is "slang". The community I targetted was defined by "i.e. will native [english] speakers understand". Which book would you recommend?

Comment: @HotLicks: Forgot examples. When I say "how going it you, dude", it would be improper/incorrect towards native speakers of English, though we Germans would understand. Likewise "March, March", which would be correct Bundeswehr-slang iff translated to German.